# How to set canvas width to width of canvas objects/text

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working with a very simple canvas set up, I am adding text to a `<canvas>`. The width of the text can vary and I don't want to set the canvas width to the longest length text. I'd like to automatically resize the canvas based on the text length.

I have seen this

```
canvasContext.measureText(textVariable).width
```

And I use it as I would if I was changing the style on any element.

```
canvas3.style.width = canvasContext.measureText(textVariable).width + "px"
```

But it doesn't work. The text reduces in size, but the canvas remains the same size.

Am I on the right track, what's not working right or is there a better solution?

**EDIT:** Regarding my issue of text reducing in size, I was changing the width and height in CSS. I should have been changing the canvas attribute like this:

```
 canvas3.setAttribute('width', '438');
 canvas3.setAttribute('height', '462');
```

My base code:

```js
const canvas3 = document.getElementById("myCanvas3");
const canvasContext = canvas3.getContext("2d");
const fontColor = 'red';
const textVariable = "COPY IS HERE"

canvasContext.font = "600 40px Proxima-nova";
canvasContext.fillStyle = fontColor;
canvasContext.textAlign = "left";
canvasContext.fillText(textVariable, 0, canvas3.height - 1);
```

```css
#myCanvas3 {
    background-color:#fafafa;
    width:240px;
    height:30px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas3"
    width="240"
    height="30"
></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you define your font sizes on the canvas instance.

Then you resize your canvas dom element using the width attribute. This will cause a "reset" of the canvas, so if you had anything drawn, you need to redraw this.
Also set the width via the style attribute to get an "actually bigger" canvas.

Then you draw the text as you had intended, setting the font size again, as this has been wiped in the reset.

```js
const canvas3 = document.getElementById("myCanvas3");
const canvasContext = canvas3.getContext("2d");
const fontColor = 'red';
const textVariable = "COPY IS HERE"

canvasContext.font = "600 40px Proxima-nova";
canvasContext.fillStyle = fontColor;
canvasContext.textAlign = "left";
canvasContext.fillText(textVariable, 0, canvas3.height - 1);
window.setTimeout(() => {
  canvas3.width = canvasContext.measureText(textVariable).width;
  canvas3.style.width = canvas3.width + 'px';
  canvasContext.font = "600 40px Proxima-nova";
  canvasContext.fillStyle = fontColor;
  canvasContext.textAlign = "left";
  canvasContext.fillText(textVariable, 0, canvas3.height - 1);
},5000);
```

```css
#myCanvas3 {
  background-color:#fafafa;
  width:240px;
  height:30px;
}
```

```html
Bigger canvas that can fit the text showing up in 5 seconds.<BR/>
<canvas id="myCanvas3"
        width="240"
        height="30"
></canvas>
```